# XSLT compare parameter external set of string values towards a string?

Tags: xml, mule, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

In Anypoint studio I use XSLT-TRANSFORMER to transform xml documents, in which i have to pass some parameter values, a set of strings.

Here is the code I am trying. The XSLT transformation i have works fine if I use the values with in XSLT but not when I externalize those parameters.

XSLT1.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:bpws="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" media-type="string" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="nreOrderType" select="'GD90','GD91','GD92'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="test">
        <xsl:value-of select="'GD90' = ($nreOrderType)"/>
    </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT2.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:bpws="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" media-type="string" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="nreOrderType"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="test">
        <xsl:value-of select="'GD90' = ($nreOrderType)"/>
    </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Passing the parameter in mule

```
{nreOrderType: "'GD90','GD91','GD92'"}
```

Expected output:

```
<test>true</test>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the parameter conventions of that tool but I suspect that using `{nreOrderType: "GD90,GD91,GD92"}` on the mule side and then `<xsl:value-of select="'GD90' = tokenize($nreOrderType, ','))"/>` on the XSLT site will work.

Comment: Seems like the parameter vslue is not passed at all. Does it work with passing a single string only?

Comment: One solution is to join all strings with a suitable delimiter as a single string and pass that as the parameter

Comment: Sandeep, did you try the proposed solution? Does this solve the problem?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, got busy with deadlines, will try it soon.

Answer (score 0):

**One solution is to pass the set of strings as a single string**, which is their concatenation, using a delimiter string that is known not to occur as a substring of any of the passed strings.

**For example**:

`<xsl:param name="nreOrderType" select="'|value1|value2|value3|'"/>`

**then to check if another string is one of the above use:**

`contains($nreOrderType, concat('|', $myString, '|'))`